# How to implement this specific action in my SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have created an `SSIS` package for my database running on `SQL Server 2014`.
This SSIS package extracts data from an `Excel` workbook (residing in a shared folder on my Windows Server) and feeds a table in my database. I have tested the package (through a SQL Job) and it works fine.

The logic behind the creation of this package is to pull data on a daily basis from that Excel workbook (the latter being updated on a daily basis). It does have a date column; so, data updated are tagged with the relevant date.

Since this SQL job will be executed on a daily basis, the table will be filled with duplicates (that is, data from Day 1 will be repeated on Day 2 and so on).

How can I deal this issue? I was thinking on adding a `T-SQL` flow to my `SSIS` package to delete the contents of the Table before it pulls the data from the `Excel` Workbook. I guess this would work but I am on the look out for a more elegant solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As your data has a date column, why not filter the data you need in the dataflow (with a conditional split)?

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that!

Comment: @Larnu After doing some reading on the topic, it seems that if I use the conditional split, I will need to have 2 tables (1 for adding the records of the day and the other table where I will dump the remaining records). Am I correct here?

Comment: Nope, you can use a conditional split with 1 table.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: So, with the conditional split, you just need to send the rows you want to the Destination. The rows you don't want, simply don't process.